# Optimize response time from API, with SQL Server involved

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a project with requirements that response time should be under 0.5sec under load as 3000 concurrency users;

I have few API which use some aggregation from SQL Server. 
when we testing it with 3000CCU average response time about 15 second. And also 500 error due to SQL can't handle so many requests. Actually requests to SQL Server interrupt with timeout) 
Our current instance is r4.2xlarge 8CPU and 61GB Memory.

All code is asynchronous without blocking operations. 
We running our app behind load balancer with 10 instances 300 CCU per instance in this case.  utilization on instances about 30%. The bottleneck  currently is SQL server.

I see few solution. Setup some big SQL, Cluster or Sharding, I'm not really sure. I'm not strong in that.

Or use cache for request. We have mostly read only data, which we can cache after aggregation.

**Update:**
I need solution to cache exactly sql responses. To order work with it late with LINQ.

But it seems there is no ready solution for that.

I found good try for that called CacheManager. But there are few problems exist with this.

1. It works with Redis only in sync mode, means use sync command instead of async.
2. There is no implementation of concurrency lock, which can occur in our case because we have 10 instances.  We need solution which work with as distributed cache.
3. There are few bugs which utilize Redis multiplexor wrong. And you constantly will have connection problem.

Please advice how to overcome this issue. How you solve it. I'm sure there are people who already solve it somehow.

Comment: If you google for `ASP.NET Core Response Caching` the very first result is [Response caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from the docs.

Comment: That is  not about response caching. It's about result cache from SQL.

Comment: SQL Server isn't slow either. Bad performance is most often caused by bad schemas, bad queries or bad access code. For example, aggregations on a *transactional* database will be slow simply because it was designed to make individual transactions go fast. A proper reporting database, eg using a star schema, can be orders of magnitude faster (ie 100,100,1000 times faster). *Explicit transactions* can also cause blocking and delays. Missing indexes are another problem

Comment: There are no any joins . Just one table involved. its time base value which we store each minute into table. There are about 8 fields. Decimal and date.

Comment: `It's about result cache from SQL` in that case you should *fix the database schema*. The caching you want to implement will hold the same data a *reporting* database would hold. Yes, result caching, or rather, generic caching is *also* available, but why cache in memory for a few minutes something that could be stored in the database and be reused by every query?

Comment: Yes for some aggregation it could be used a well. But for example we are returning data for some live graph, this array contains value for each minute which already stored in this format in database. User of API request time range that he want to get. And we return this data to him. There is just no way to store it in SQL in different format. It's already aggregated and stored by minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197378/discussion-between-grinay-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

I enable query store on sql and monitor all missing indexes. Ef core generates some of request absolutely different way that expected. After creating missing indexes performance became much better. But i still have problem to handle required CCU. I explore all existing solution which extend ef core to cache. Most of them was written in sync version. Which just can’t utilize all benefits of async. As well i did’t found any distributed cache that implement distributed lock. Finally I create this lib which extend ef core and and distributed cache in redis .cache allow us scale a lot more. And now everything just flight;)  leave it here, for someone who have performance issue like me. https://github.com/grinay/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DistributedCache